# Weighted load balancing Nginx

Tags: node.js, web, nginx

Its my first time working with Nginx, and i started doing some balancing.

I have the next shema:

- Nodejs app1 running (IP:5050).
- Nodejs app2 running (IP:6060).

And i have this load balancing config:

```
upstream backend {
   #least_conn;
   #ip_hash;
   server 172.29.24.1:5050 weight=3;
   server 172.29.24.1:6060 weight=5;
}
```

I need to get this:

> Make 1 of every 3 times load the first application and 2 of every
>   3 for the second application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution

```
upstream backend {
   #least_conn;
   #ip_hash;
   server 172.29.24.1:5050 weight=1;
   server 172.29.24.1:6060 weight=2;
}
```